# RxJs using Scan and DebounceTime to rate limit network calls, Invalidate scan accumalator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using `ngrx` to maintain state in my application.
I need to update server with current state of application frequently, but I don't want to overwhelm server with too many requests.

My @effect is some what like

```ts
@Injectable()
class MyEffect {
    @Effect()
    effect = this.action.ofType(UPDATE)
        .scan(collectAllChanges,emptyValue)
        .debounceTime(2000)
        .switchMap(data => update(data).map(() => new UpdateStoreAction(data)));
}
```

`CollectAllChanges` is a method which takes last `accumulated`value and new `changes` and build new `accumulated` value

Now what I require is to invalidate `accumulated` value in `scan` operator when `debounceTime` Operator emits.

Any Hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is easier to use [`.bufferTime(2000)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferTime) to have all changes be accumulated and propagated every 2seconds instead of doing this manually?

If you want to have a combination of the debounce backoff with a regular [`buffer()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) you can also do something like this:

```
const source = this.action.ofType(UPDATE); source   
  .buffer(source.debounceTime(2000))   
  .switchMap(buffer => update(buffer)
    .mapTo(new UpdateStoreAction(data))
  );
```

This way all actions are buffered until the source quiets down for 2seconds before emitting the buffer.

Comment: thanks , I think `bufferTime` and `filter` to remove empty array will work best for my case

Comment: after thinking little bit more , `bufferTime` does not work like debounce where it does not wait for lean time for source to pause for emitting

Comment: I have added an additional example using buffer(closingNotifier) which might be a fitting solution for you.